# Checar variação de palavras em uma frase com RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho um código que verifica frases que o usuário digita e estava tentado mais sem muito sucesso, fazer um código usando *RegExp* que verifique se o usuário digitou uma determinada frase sem ou com variações de palavras.

**Exemplo:**
"Eu uso o Facebook" ou "Eu uso o Google"

As duas frases são quase idênticas com somente uma variação de palavra.

Eu queria que esse código verifique se o usuário digitou essa frase com possíveis variações predeterminadas.

Eu não entendo muito sobre, mas acho que seria mais ou menos assim:

```
"Eu uso o google".exec( /^Eu uso o [google, facebook]$/i );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `.exec()` está ao contrário, deve ser `regex.exec(str)`, e no caso de só querer um booleano pode usar o `.test()`. Entretanto pode tirar o $ e fazer assim:

```
var str = "Eu uso o google";
var regex = /^Eu uso o [google, facebook]/i;
var teste = regex.test(str); // true
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9nwC7/

Um site que eu costumo usar para testar expressões regulares é: http://regex101.com/r/bS4nT8/1